# Safest weed killers?

Tags: safety, weeds

Are there any weed killers that aren't endocrine disruptors or carcinogens?

I'm at war with dandelions, but prefer a few dandelions to cancer or reproductive damage, most days.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for the [Gardening and Landscaping site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1369/gardening-and-landscaping?referrer=urk6w4I8INOYMjBnRn68AQ2) currently in commitment phase.  You might consider committing to it yourself if you're into working in the yard!

Answer (score 1):

I was shopping at the local organic supply store the other day, and was advised to try a concentrated vinegar product. Check out this advice -

http://www.garden-counselor-lawn-care.com/vinegar-weed-killer.html

Couldn't hurt to try! I am going to!

Comment: Answers that rely extensively on links, can become useless if the linked site goes away.  Please try to summarize the linked content here.

Answer (score -1):

Preen

[image]
<sub>(source: [jensenonline.com](http://jensenonline.com/cares/webimages/13819107c.jpg))</sub>

See why, check out the [MSDS sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20150320235816/http://www.preen.com:80/msds/1006_2463795.ashx). It shown no registered carcinogens.

Comment: I don't think you can preen your lawn can you? The OP didn't say it was his lawn so I'm just guessing.

Comment: "Trifluralin -- Herbicide found in: Preen, Preen & Green, Scotts Garden Weed Preventer, Trefanocide, Treficon, and Trust. Kills annual grasses and broadleaf weeds. Highly toxic to fish and other aquatic organisms. It is a possible cause of cancer and a probable cause of endocrine disruption. It has been demonstrated that it causes reproductive effects, kidney damage, liver damage, sensitivity, and irritation."  Unfortunately, not quite what I want next to the garden.  :-/